# mysql return max n amount of rows with same value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a wordpress database of which I'd like to select only 5 rows (posts) that have the same meta value. That means if I have 100 posts, of which each 20 have the same meta value, I'd get 5 times 5 rows with the same meta value.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` a, `wp_postmeta` b WHERE a.ID = b.post_id AND b.meta_key = 'mykey' AND a.post_type='code' AND a.post_status='publish' LIMIT DISTINCT(meta_value) 5
```

ofcourse the LIMIT DISCINCT(meta_value) 5 is not representable but it shows that per meta_value I'd only like to have 5 rows.

How can I simply solve this issue?

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions. You need, however, a column that defines the ordering of post meta:

```
select * 
from wp_posts p
inner join (
    select pm.*, row_number() over(partition by post_id order by id desc) rn
    from wp_postmeta
    where b.meta_key = 'mykey'
) pm on p.id = pm.post_id and pm.rn <= 5
where p.post_type = 'code' and p.post_status = 'publish'
```